# "Не" с причастиями пишется слитно?

Tags: морфология, частица-не, причастия

Почему **не** пишется слитно с причастиями (*неглаженное* бельё, *нетоплённые* помещения)? Ведь причастие имеет свойства глагола, а глагол с частицей **не** пишется раздельно. Можно ли писать **не** с причастиями раздельно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Неглаженое (мятое) белье (прилагательное), белье еще не глаженное (причастие).

2) С глаголом "топить" сложнее

От глагола топить образуется причастие топленный, в котором и при отсутствии зависимого слова могут писаться две буквы НН в зависимости от значения:

топить (1) – поддерживать огонь в очаге, в печи:топленная печь, нетопленная печь (печь, которую топили или не топили) – две буквы НН в причастии, значение действия;

топить (2) – обогревать помещение:
– нетопленое (холодное) помещение – одна буква Н в прилагательном, значение результата действия,

–  давно не топленная комната (комната, которую давно не обогревали) – две буквы НН в причастии при наличии зависимого слова;

топить (3) – нагревая, расплавлять: от глагола образуется отглагольное прилагательное топлёный (топлёное молоко).

ПРИМЕРЫ

Тяжелый год. Нетопленная печь. Глухая ночь, а в доме – ни полена. 
Эдвард почувствовал, что в нетопленом кабинете холодно. 
В холодной, давно не топленной комнате при желтой, как янтарь, свече передо мной сидела немолодая женщина.