# Нетопленая/нетопленная

Tags: орфография, части-речи, удвоенные-буквы

Я что-то совсем запуталась с частью речи и количеством Н...

> *И ветер жалобно, тоскливо
>
>   Застонет, загудит в трубе.
>
>   И будет зябко, сиротливо
>
>   В моей **нетопленой** избе.*

Answer (score 1):

> нетопленый*, прил.
>
> НЕТОПЛЕНЫЙ, -ая, -ое. Такой, который не обогревали, не протапливали. Н-ая изба за неделю выстыла.

(http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)

От глагола топить образуется причастие топленный, в котором и при отсутствии зависимого слова могут писаться две буквы НН в зависимости от значения:

топить (1) – поддерживать огонь в очаге, в печи:топленная печь, нетопленная печь (печь, которую топили или не топили) – две буквы НН в причастии, значение действия;

топить (2) – обогревать помещение: – нетопленое (холодное) помещение – одна буква Н в прилагательном, значение результата действия,

Подробнее в ответе Vera здесь: ["Не" с причастиями пишется слитно?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/45564/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE)