# Почему правильно "нетопленый"?

Tags: орфография

Почему в слове ***нетопленый*** одна Н?

Comment: Похожий вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/438031/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f

Answer (score 3):

> Одна буква Н пишется в суффиксах прилагательных, образованных от глаголов несовершенного вида: *коптить — копченая колбаса, вялить — вяленая рыба.*

(За дальнейшее по ссылке не отвечаю. Их исключения далеко не все образованы от глаголов, но процитированное вроде всё верно.)

[Источник](http://21vu.ru/publ/688/25092)

***Нетопленый*** — прилагательное: *нетопленая комната*. Причастие ***не топленный*** пишется раздельно и — да, с двумя Н. Оно употребляется обычно с зависимыми словами или когда важно подчеркнуть отсутствие действия: *давно не топленная баня*.

Answer (score 0):

Пишется с одной Н,так как слово образовано от глагола несовершенного вида и при этом нет зависимых слов.

Answer (score 0):

В написании *нетопленный/нетопленый*  наблюдались колебания в связи с разными значениями глагола *топить*:

1. ТОПИТЬ, нсв. (св. вытопить и истопить). что. 1. **Разводить и поддерживать огонь** в печи, очаге и т.п. Т. печь дровами. Т. камин. 2. **Обогревать (помещение)**, разводя огонь в печи или включая отопительные приборы; отапливать. Т. баню, дом.

Получалось: 1) нетопленая (холодная) комната – это явное прилагательное, одна буква Н; 2) нетопленая/нетопленная печь – это печь, которую не топили, значение действия сохранено, по смыслу это причастие и при отсутствии зависимых слов.

Но в настоящее время, как я понимаю,  **орфография упрощена**: при отсутствии зависимых слов это всегда прилагательное *(нетопленая комната, нетопленая печь*), но: *еще не топленная печь* – причастие, две буквы НН.

Примеры:

Тяжёлый год. **Нетопленная** печь. Глухая ночь, А в доме – ни полена (В. Богданов, 1972).

Можно б и русскую печь затопить, девок теплом побаловать, да опасливо ― дымить начнет, столько времени **нетопленная**. [Евгений Носов. Шопен, соната номер два (1973)]

В углу грязно-белой глыбой темнела **нетопленая** русская печь. [Александра Маринина, Александр Горкин. Шестикрылый серафим (1991)]

Славная была изба у Никитича, да только стояла она как **нетопленая** печь, ― не было хозяйки. [Д. Н. Мамин-Сибиряк. Три конца (1890)]

Comment: Частотность в Нацкорпусе. Нетопленый и нетопленный — 214:155, причем полно нетопленных (нн) помещений, например : Наконец через час нас отвели в мёрзлый, нетопленный лагерный изолятор. [В. Т. Шаламов. Колымские рассказы (1954-1961)]. Никакого порядка нет. Но по правилам вроде должно быть одно н, если нет зависимых слов.